# How to split the string into segments in python

Tags: python, string

I have a string built from a few segments, which are not separated, but not overlap. This looks like that:

```
<python><regex><split>
```

I would like to split in into:

```
<python>, <regex>, <split>
```

I'm looking for the most efficient way to do that, and in the same time with as little code as possible. I could change '>' into '> ' etc., but I don't want to do any redundant operations. Is it possible to use regex to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [re.findall](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re
your_string = '<python><regex><split>'
parts = re.findall(r'<.+?>', your_string)  
print parts # ['<python>', '<regex>', '<split>']
```

Comment: This is the function I needed

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> re.sub(r'<(.+?)>',r'<\1>,','<python><regex><split>')[:-1]
'<python>,<regex>,<split>'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input data is really that simple, you can just use the `.replace()` method that's built into strings.

```
>>> '<python><regex><split>'.replace('><', '>, <')
'<python>, <regex>, <split>'
```

If it's more complex, you should give a better example of input/expected output.

Comment: It's a bit redundant, because it requires to modify the string only to split it afterwards, I'd like to avoid such operation if possible.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. You want the result to be a list or similar which contains each of the elements you're looking for then ?